# How can I remove, from Windows Media Center (WIN7), a manually-set and daily-repeating program?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

While it's easy to unset a normally-programmed recording in WMC (right click on the listing and choose "Do Not Record"), it's not so easy if it's been set up manually (e.g. when the program guide shows "No data available" and one inputs the recording details manually: start & end time etc., etc.)

The only time I can delete the setting is when I try to set two additional programs at the same time, and then the conflict (max two simultaneous recordings allowed by my dual tuner) allows me to choose one to delete - but I don't want to have to do this every day, or leave it then have to delete the unwanted recordings afterwards.

Does anyone know how to get to the manual setting to edit or delete it, please?

PS And thanks to the curmudgeon who wouldn't recognise a question that's meaningful to at least one member of the SuperUser community. You obviously don't rely on WMC...

Answer (score 0):

As no convenient solution has been posted in nearl;y 2 weeks, I will post the obvious but ***inconvenient*** solution:

- Settings/TV/Recorder/Clear_Recording_Schedule

As I have an extensive set of regular recordings set, as well as numerous films I hope to record next time they're shown (so far prevented by conflicts with other higher-priority recordings) but which are now mostly inaccessible, it will be a nuisance to implement.

However, if some bright spark can see a better method, I will be grateful (but as the bonus options appear to start at 100, I'm not so desperate as to offer over half my existing points).